# Cannot open i3 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, i3-wm, tiling

I install `i3` with

`sudo apt install i3`

Then I command to check version is

```
i3 version 4.17.1 (2019-08-30) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
```

When I logout my profile and switch GUI from `Ubuntu on Wayland` to `i3`
the system forces me to log in again.

picture -> [when I switch GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpnoy.jpg)

Can you help me, please? ;_; (PS. It's my first time to install i3)